# Laravel DB relations

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to connect users table with user_info. I've found some posts about it and it works, but I've troubles with user_info->id autoincrement.

If I set it to:
$table->increments('id');

I'm getting error that no default value is set, it works only if I add 
$table->integer('id')->nullable($value = true);

Here is what I got for now:

User model

```
public function userinfo()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Userinfo');
}
```

Userinfo model

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Migration/table structure

```
    public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('user_info', function (Blueprint $table) {
                //There is a problem, if I don't add user_id it says that user_id doesnt exists, so I created user_id and decided to set id to autoincrement but it doesnt works so I made it like that 
                $table->integer('id')->nullable($value = true);
                $table->foreign('id')->references('id')->on('users');
                $table->integer('user_id');

$table->string('avatar',255)->default('notset.jpg')->nullable($value = true);
                $table->string('looking_for',255)->nullable($value = true);
                $table->string('steam_nick',40)->nullable($value = true);
                $table->integer('age')->length(3)->nullable($value = true);
                $table->integer('isFriendly')->length(2)->nullable($value = true);
                $table->integer('isToxic')->length(2)->nullable($value = true);
                $table->integer('isLeader')->length(2)->nullable($value = true);
                $table->integer('isFunny')->length(2)->nullable($value = true);
                $table->integer('isSkilled')->length(2)->nullable($value = true);
                $table->text('description')->nullable($value = true);
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

Finally UserinfoController

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {
      $user = User::findOrFail($id); //Get role specified by id


       $this->validate($request, [
           'steam_nick'=>'max:120',
           'looking_for'=>'required',
           'avatar'=>'',
           'description'=>'max:450',
           'age'=>'min:2'
       ]);
       $input = $request->only(['steam_nick', 'looking_for', 'description','avatar','age']); //Retreive the name, email and password fields

       $userinfo = new Userinfo();
       if ($userinfo->user_id == null ) {
           $userinfo->steam_nick = $request->steam_nick;
           $userinfo->looking_for = $request->looking_for;
           $userinfo->description = $request->description;
           $userinfo->avatar = $request->avatar;
           $userinfo->age = $request->age;
           $user->Userinfo()->save($userinfo);
       } else {
           $user->Userinfo()->update($input);
       }

    }
```

Phpmyadmin
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuiId.png)

All I need is to set id in user_info same as id in users. I don't need user_id, but couldn't make it works other way, but I'm sure it's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, let's break it down piece by piece.

First, what I like to do is specifically declare what my table column is as the second argument on any `hasOne` and `belongsTo` in a model. It's not strictly necessary since Laravel does some voodoo magic to guess what the table name is - but I recommend it because it makes the relationship very clear. So, I would do this on the user model:

```
public function userinfo()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Userinfo', 'user_id'); // it references user_id on your user_info table.
}
```

Next, let's look at your `user_info` migration. You were having problems with your primary key `id` because you were trying to set it as `integer` when it needs to be `increments`. We'll tweak the first three lines:

```
$table->increments('id')->unsigned();
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users'); // foreign references the user_id field in this table, since that's what's making the connection between users and users_info, we point back to the user's id
```

At this point, if you are able, I recommend `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`. It might help with any weird database structures you have prior. This is optional, though. You can try it if it doesn't work straight away.

Now in the controller, I noticed that you were previously referencing `$user->Userinfo()->update($input);`, but you named the relationship `userinfo()` in your user model. This is probably one of the things that was giving you an issue. They must match. Try setting up your controller like so:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id); //Get role specified by id

    $this->validate($request, [
        'steam_nick'=>'max:120',
        'looking_for'=>'required',
        'avatar'=>'',
        'description'=>'max:450',
        'age'=>'min:2'
    ]);

    $input = $request->only(['steam_nick', 'looking_for', 'description','avatar','age']); //Retreive the name, email and password fields

    // Does this user have an info record? If not, create it, else update it.
    if (is_null($user->userinfo)) {
        // Since you already collected the data in the $input variable, we simply array_merge it with the user's id
        Userinfo::create(array_merge([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
        ], $input));
    } else {
        $user->userinfo()->update($input);
    }

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

So, basically what we are doing is checking to see if the user has a related record in the `user_info` table. If not, create it with the data. If so, simply update it. Since in our migration we declare that `user_id` cannot be null, we have to grab the user's id off the `$user` variable, and you've already grabbed all of the necessary data for the `user_info` table and put it in the `$input` variable, we simply `array_merge()` those two arrays when creating the user's info record.

Otherwise, if the related record already exists, we simply update the `user_info` record using our relationship `->userinfo()`.

Try that and let me know how it works.

Comment: Thanks Sir it's clear now, but I'm wonering why I get error since we set up user id SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `user_info` (`steam_nick`, `looking_for`, `description`, `avatar`, `age`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (asd, begginer, asd, ww3theme.jpg, 12, 2018-06-06 15:03:42, 2018-06-06 15:03:42))

Comment: The error you are getting is presumably because no ``user_id`` is being inserted. Are you getting this error from the controller code example I gave you or elsewhere?